# Trying to find alternative way to express LINQ expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

Further to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088108/alternative-way-to-do-firstordefault-in-linq) I hadI've been able to simplify my query but am still having an issue with the MySQL provider.

I've got a membership table that records whether a user is a member of a list. When an update to a user's membership occurs a new record is written and the previous records are left as is which allows a history of their memberships to be maintained. To get a user's membership status involves selecting their most recent entry.

An example of some user list membership data is below. The aim is to find a LINQ expression that groups by list and user but only returns the row with most recently inserted record.

```
List Name, Username, Comment, ExpiresOn, Inserted
Test List, joeb, second update, 2012-03-13 16:55:03, 2012-01-31 22:28:40
Test List, joeb, first update, 2012-02-13 16:55:01, 2012-01-31 22:28:39
Test List, joeb, initial, 2012-01-13 16:55:02, 2012-01-31 22:28:38
```

My LINQ expression is as below.

```
var query = from mem in db.UserListMemberships
            where
             mem.Inserted >= (from mem2 in db.UserListMemberships where mem.UserID == mem2.UserID && mem.UserListID == mem2.UserListID orderby mem2.Inserted descending select mem2.Inserted).FirstOrDefault()
             select mem;
```

The issue is I'm getting an exception from the MySQL entity provider of "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'Extent1.UserID' in 'where clause'". Is there any other way I could write e expression that might get around the MySQL exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
var query =
    from mem in db.UserListMemberships
    group mem by mem.UserID into mems
    select mems.OrderByDescending(m => m.Inserted).First();
```

Comment: Using First like that generates an exception within the Linq-to-EF infrastructure "System.NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.".