# One-to-Many EF query to get most recent row of the many

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I have the following POCOs:

```cs
public class TrackToken
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength( 500 )]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TrackLog> Logs { get; set; }
}

public class TrackLog
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TrackToken Parent { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ServerID { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to be able to make a EF LINQ query that can return every TrackToken, and join with the most recent TrackLog for that TrackToken.

I've tried code like:

```cs
TrackTokens
.Select( t => new
{
    ID = t.ID,
    Comment = t.Comment,
    CreationTime = t.CreationTime,

    RecentLog = t.Logs.OrderByDescending( l => l.Time ).FirstOrDefault(),
} );
```

But somewhere along the line of executing the query, I get

`EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.`

`InnerException: NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.`

Which appears to be related to the usage of FirstOrDefault.

I've also tried something similar to this, but I'm unsure of how to get the ServerID column

```cs
TrackTokens
.Select( t => new
{
    ID = t.ID,
    Comment = t.Comment,
    CreationTime = t.CreationTime,

    LastSeen = t.Logs.Max( l => l.Time ),
    LastServerID = // how do I get the ServerID column of the most recent record?
} );
```

What's the go-to method of performing a query on this sort of relationship?

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: The database is MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the `LastServerID` in your `Select` statement using:

```
LastServerID = t.Logs.OrderByDescending(l => l.Time)
    .Select(l => l.ServerID).FirstOrDefault()
```

(Probably you have to make the return type nullable with `Select(l => (int?)l.ServerID)` to take the case into a account the a `TrackToken` does not have any `TrackLog`. The same probably for the time: `Max(l => (DateTime?)l.Time)`)

It would work with SQL Server. However, the real problem appears to be that the MySQL provider for EF does not support `FirstOrDefault` in a projection (which is also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088108/alternative-way-to-do-firstordefault-in-linq)).

Comment: If the issue is in the MySQL provider, does that imply that the only options here would be workarounds (as FirstByDefault works with SQL server)?

Comment: @RyanS: First thing I'd check is if you're using the latest provider (maybe it is supported in newer versions). Other than that you have to workaround it, I guess, yes. The only idea I had right now is running multiple DB queries, loading token and log separately. I'd also ask at MySQL forums for official confirmation that this is *really* not  supported and what's the recommended workaround. Or maybe ask a new question here what's the best way to reformulate the query without the use of `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I upgraded the MySQL provider from 6.5.4 to 6.7.4 and that seems to have done the trick for `FirstOrDefault`! It did however introduce a whole new headache of assembly redirects and DbProviderFactories, but that's a whole different story. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    context.TrackTokens.OrderByDecending(t => t.LastServerID).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help, as my TrackToken POCO doesn't have a "LastServerID", and such an ordering wouldn't be what I'm looking for, anyway (ServerIDs don't increment, they're going to be mostly random).

Comment: Can you just add a timestamp on the entry then and order by that.